# How to Synchronise functions in AsyncWebsocketConsumer in channels?

Tags: django, asynchronous, websocket, synchronization, channel

I am using AsyncWebsocketConsumer in channels to create basic group messaging
saving in a database or any other process who's data should not be sent to WebSocket works fine, but when I try to fetch all previous messages at socket open function, it is not sending data to socket but data is retrieved...

basically, it is running both processes parallelly, so do I need to use syncWebsocketConsumer and use async and await were required ? or is there anything to make few things synchronized in async consumers ?

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
     ...
     async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        user = text_data_json['user']
        print(text_data_json['type'])
        #using init_messages for fetching
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,{
                'type': text_data_json['type'],
                'message':message,
                'user': text_data_json['user']
            }
        )
        print("sended")

     async def init_messages(self,event):
        messages = await sync_to_async(get_last_10_messages)(self.room_name)
        print(messages)
        messages = self.parse_messages(messages)
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'messages':messages,
       
        }))
```

parse_messages simply gives dictionary

In room.html

```
chatSocket.onopen = function(e){
                    chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                        'type': "init_messages",
                        'message':"",
                        'user': user_username,
                    }));
                    console.log('for debug')
                }
```